# Tabular alignment issue in a loop

Tags: tables, etoolbox

I'm getting some odd table alignment issues with a table that I'm constructing inside of a `\whileboolexpr`.

The `.tex` file is the following:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{pcnt}
\setcounter{pcnt}{0}

\newenvironment{defineperson}[1]
{\csgdef{person\thepcnt}{#1}}
{\stepcounter{pcnt}}

\newcommand\persontitle[1]{\csgdef{persontitle\thepcnt}{#1}}
\newcommand\personmail[1]{\csgdef{personmail\thepcnt}{#1}}
\newcommand\showperson[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\newcommand\maketabular[1]{\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |} \hline #1 \end{tabular}}

\newcounter{nada} 
\newcommand\makepersonrtable{%
  \setcounter{nada}{0}%
  \maketabular{%
  \whileboolexpr
    { test {\ifnumcomp{\value{nada}}{<}{\value{pcnt}}} }%
    {\showperson{\csuse{person\thenada}} & \csuse{persontitle\thenada} & \csuse{personmail\thenada} \\ \hline \stepcounter{nada} }
  }}

\begin{defineperson}{Mr.}
  \persontitle{Wall Eye}
  \personmail{weye@gmail.com}
\end{defineperson}

\begin{defineperson}{Mrs.}
  \persontitle{Perch}
  \personmail{perch@gmail.com}
\end{defineperson}

\begin{defineperson}{Mr.}
  \persontitle{Brook Trout}
  \personmail{btrout@gmail.com}
\end{defineperson}

\begin{document}

\makepersonrtable

\end{document}
```

This does generate a table as I would have expected, but the alignment is off - e.g.,
[image]

Notice that the first "Mr." is not aligned with the second row.  Also notice the extra vertical lines at the bottom.

Any idea what's going on here? I know there are other ways of making tables, but this I'm trying a few alternatives as a learning exercise.

Comment: The obvious problem is that a cell is started before `\whileboolexpr` realizes that it must end the cycle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The non alignment is caused by spurious spaces; the extraneous bars are caused by the fact that when `\whileboolexpr` decides the cycle has ended, a `tabular` cell has already been started.

The usual method is to prepare the whole table body and then deliver it. In this case this is complicated by the variable data you pass, so the lines must be expanded before appending to the body previously collected.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{pcnt}

\newenvironment{defineperson}[1]
{\csgdef{person\thepcnt}{#1}}
{\stepcounter{pcnt}}

\newcommand\persontitle[1]{\csgdef{persontitle\thepcnt}{#1}}
\newcommand\personmail[1]{\csgdef{personmail\thepcnt}{#1}}
\newcommand\showperson[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\newcommand\maketabular[1]{\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |} \hline #1 \end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\personrtablebody}{} % initialization

\newcounter{nada}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\makepersonrtable{%
  \renewcommand\personrtablebody{}%
  \setcounter{nada}{0}%
  \maketabular{%
  \whileboolexpr
    { test {\ifnumcomp{\value{nada}}{<}{\value{pcnt}}} }%
    {%
     \begingroup\protected@edef\x{\endgroup
       \noexpand\appto{\noexpand\personrtablebody}{%
         \showperson{\csuse{person\thenada}} & 
         \csuse{persontitle\thenada} &
         \csuse{personmail\thenada} \noexpand\\
         \noexpand\hline
       }%
     }\x
     \stepcounter{nada}%
    }%
    \personrtablebody
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{defineperson}{Mr.}
  \persontitle{Wall Eye}
  \personmail{weye@gmail.com}
\end{defineperson}

\begin{defineperson}{Mrs.}
  \persontitle{Perch}
  \personmail{perch@gmail.com}
\end{defineperson}

\begin{defineperson}{Mr.}
  \persontitle{Brook Trout}
  \personmail{btrout@gmail.com}
\end{defineperson}

\begin{document}

\makepersonrtable

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!  I thought it was something like that, but I couldn't tell where it was coming from.

Answer (score 2):

Using your existing setup, two things are going wrong here:

1. The mis-alignment is caused by a space that is passed to `\maketabular` with the call to `\stepcounter{nada}`. Remove this space.
2. A new cell is started with the call to `\whileboolexpr`, leading to the final row-insertion at the bottom. To get around this, I've shuffled some of the commands around, forcing a fixed first row (when `\value{nada}=0`). Counter stepping and testing of `\whileboolexpr` is performed in the last cell of each row, avoiding the start of a new row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

\newcounter{pcnt}\setcounter{pcnt}{0}

\newenvironment{defineperson}[1]
  {\csgdef{person\thepcnt}{#1}}
  {\stepcounter{pcnt}}

\newcommand\persontitle[1]{\csgdef{persontitle\thepcnt}{#1}}
\newcommand\personmail[1]{\csgdef{personmail\thepcnt}{#1}}
\newcommand\showperson[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\newcommand\maketabular[1]{\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |} \hline #1 \\ \hline \end{tabular}}

\newcounter{nada} 
\newcommand\makepersonrtable{%
  \setcounter{nada}{1}%
  \maketabular{%
  \showperson{\csuse{person0}} & \csuse{persontitle0} & \csuse{personmail0}
  \whileboolexpr
    { test {\ifnumcomp{\value{nada}}{<}{\value{pcnt}}} }%
    { \\ \hline \showperson{\csuse{person\thenada}} & \csuse{persontitle\thenada} & \csuse{personmail\thenada}\stepcounter{nada}}%
  }}

\begin{defineperson}{Mr.}
  \persontitle{Wall Eye}
  \personmail{weye@gmail.com}
\end{defineperson}

\begin{defineperson}{Mrs.}
  \persontitle{Perch}
  \personmail{perch@gmail.com}
\end{defineperson}

\begin{defineperson}{Mr.}
  \persontitle{Brook Trout}
  \personmail{btrout@gmail.com}
\end{defineperson}

\begin{document}

\makepersonrtable

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problems with your code having been explained, here the job is done by `\xintFor*` from [xinttools](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint). No need for the `nada` counter.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xinttools}
\expandafter\chardef\csname xint_c_i\endcsname 1
% the line above to circumvent a bug with a missing definition in xinttools v1.09k. 

\newcounter{pcnt}
\setcounter{pcnt}{0}

\newenvironment{defineperson}[1]
    {\csgdef{person\thepcnt}{#1}}
    {\stepcounter{pcnt}}

\newcommand\persontitle[1]{\csgdef{persontitle\thepcnt}{#1}}
\newcommand\personmail [1]{\csgdef{personmail\thepcnt}{#1}}
\newcommand\showperson [1]{\textbf{#1}}

\newcommand\maketabular[1]
    {\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |}\hline #1\end{tabular}}


% Let's use \xintFor to generate an alignment
% \xintSeq{0}{\value{pcnt}-1} generates {0}{1}{2}...{N-1} with N=value of pcnt counter.
% \xintFor* is for such "braced" lists, \xintFor for comma separated lists.
\newcommand\makepersonrtable{%
  \maketabular{%
  \xintFor* ##1 in {\xintSeq{0}{\value{pcnt}-1}}
  \do
    {\showperson{\csuse{person##1}} & 
     \csuse{persontitle##1}         & 
     \csuse{personmail##1}          \\ \hline }
  }}

\begin{defineperson}{Mr.}
  \persontitle{Wall Eye}
  \personmail{weye@gmail.com}
\end{defineperson}

\begin{defineperson}{Mrs.}
  \persontitle{Perch}
  \personmail{perch@gmail.com}
\end{defineperson}

\begin{defineperson}{Mr.}
  \persontitle{Brook Trout}
  \personmail{btrout@gmail.com}
\end{defineperson}

\begin{document}

\makepersonrtable

\end{document}
```

[image: tabularloop]

Comment: Very interesting - I've learned so much from all of these answers.  Thanks!