# etoolbox: problem with the last row in an table automated

Tags: tables, automation, etoolbox

I want to automate a long table as follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{test}
\newcounter{count}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
\whileboolexpr{test {\ifnumequal{\thetest}{0}}}
{\ifnumless{\thecount}{10}{\addtocounter{count}{1}Hello & Hello}
{Bye & Bye\addtocounter{test}{1}}\\\hline}\setcounter{test}{0}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

but there is a problem with the last line. How can I fix that? I think the problem is with `\whileboolexpr`, but I don't know how fix it.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156682/tabular-alignment-issue-in-a-loop